# Assigning value to an object

Tags: php

just need help regarding my program.

anyway i have the following data in array.

```
0 - 10 - desc1 - 1 - PCS - 11 - I1 - 0060000714 - 0020730027
1 - 20 - desc2 - 2 - BOX - 44 - I1 - 0060000714 - 0020730027
2 - 30 - desc3 - 3 - PER - 99 - DI - 0060000715 - 0020730027
3 - 40 - desc4 - 4 - PCS - 176 - I1 - 0060000714 - 0020730027
4 - 50 - desc5 - 5 - BOX - 275 - I1 - 0060000714 - 0020730027
5 - 60 - desc6 - 6 - PCS - 396 - I1 - 0060000714 - 0020730027
```

what i did is i use foreach

```
foreach($result as $tmp){
   $po_item_no = $tmp['item_no'];
   $po_details = $tmp['item_desc'];
   $po_details = urlencode($po_details);
   $unit = $tmp['item_unit'];
   $qty = $tmp['item_qty'];
   $unit_price = $tmp['item_amt'];
   $net_price = $unit_price * $qty;

   echo $po_item_no.' - '.$po_details.' - '.$qty.' - '.$unit.' - '.$net_price.'<br>';
}
```

the above code works properly and echos the value.

but whenever i use this code it only shows me 1 line and terminate it after.

```
$item = new PO_Item();
foreach($result as $tmp){
   $po_item_no = $tmp['item_no'];
   $po_details = $tmp['item_desc'];
   $po_details = urlencode($po_details);
   $unit = $tmp['item_unit'];
   $qty = $tmp['item_qty'];
   $unit_price = $tmp['item_amt'];
   $net_price = $unit_price * $qty;

   echo $po_item_no.' - '.$po_details.' - '.$qty.' - '.$unit.' - '.$net_price.'<br>';

   $item->addToItem(_Item::__set_state(
      array(
         'PO_ITEM' => $po_item_no,
         'SHORT_TEXT' => $po_details,
         'PLANT' => $plant,
         'MATL_GROUP' => '1234',
         'QUANTITY' => $qty,
         'PO_UNIT' => $unit,
         'NET_PRICE' => $net_price,
         'ACCTASSCAT' => 'Z'
      )
   ));
}
```

that code only show 1 record and not displaying the 6 record.

what do you think is wrong with my code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Maybe `addToItem` throws error? Try echoing something after this function call.

Comment: Please comment `addToItem` code and check first its coming or not.

Comment: i did enable the error and it give me this Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid value, please provide a string, "double" given' in /srv/sapxi/PORequest/src/StructType/_Item.php:649

Comment: can you please tell us which line 649?

Comment: what is weird whenever i manual the data it works properly like this.

$item->addToItem(_Item::__set_state(
                    array(
                        'PO_ITEM' => '1',
                        'SHORT_TEXT' => 'desc1',
                        'PLANT' => '1000',
                        'MATL_GROUP' => '7501',
                        'QUANTITY' => '1',
                        'PO_UNIT' => '1',
                        'NET_PRICE' => '1',
                        'TAX_CODE' => '1',
                        'ACCTASSCAT' => 'Z'
                    )
            ));

Comment: @RuchishParikh `code`public function setNET_PRICE($nET_PRICE = null)
    {
        // validation for constraint: string
        if (!is_null($nET_PRICE) && !is_string($nET_PRICE)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid value, please provide a string, "%s" given', gettype($nET_PRICE)), __LINE__);
        }
        $this->NET_PRICE = $nET_PRICE;
        return $this;
    }`code`

Comment: solve it already by converting the integer value of net_price to string. $net_price = ($unit_price * $qty); $net_price = strval($net_price); the existing code only accept string value. anyway thank you very much for quick response.